# Is there a way to have a practitioner with several organizations in fhir

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have a practitioner resource but the practitioner works in several hospitals, how can I relate several organizations with one practitioner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple PractitionerRole resources.  One for each Organization and use the reference to the same Practitioner with PractitionerRole.practitoner.